# Accept self-signed as well as CA-issued client certificates in NGINX, but clearly tag those successfully validated as CA-issued?

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, x509certificate, client-certificates

Is it possible to configure NGINX in a way that accepts self-signed as well as CA-issued client certificates, with the CA-issued receiving proper validation and indicating this fact in a variable (enable setting a security header for proxied applications)?

The standard NGINX `$ssl_client_verify` variable of `ngx_http_ssl_module` doesn't provide enough context to determine what particular checks the certificate passed with `optional_no_ca`.

Comment: What kind of use case is this where arbitrary certificates are accepted and it is not sufficient to distinguish binary between trusted and non-trusted. Also, based on [the documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#var_ssl_client_verify) it should actually give the reason for the certificate validation failure. It is not clear how this is not sufficient, i.e. what more is needed?

Comment: For an endpoint where clients can either authenticate (MTLS) with a proper PKI-bound certificate, or a self-signed certificate where its public key is pre-registered with the endpoint (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8705).

Comment: Since anybody can create a self-signed certificate blindly trusting any self-signed certificate is likely a bad idea. So I assume that you want to accept CA signed certificates directly at nginx while forwarding any self-signed certificates to some additional logic which then checks if the certificate can be accepted. In which case you could actually just forward any certificate to this logic which can not be positively validated inside nginx.

Comment: Do you reckon this behaviour can be configured in NGINX? The application has the wherewithal to determine if a claimed client identity requires a CA or self-signed certificate, and to check the public key for the latter.

Comment: I don't think it can be configured in nginx. And if the check ultimately depends on the public key in the certificate it does not actually matter if this is a self-signed certificate or an expired one or a revoked one etc since the trust is solely connected to the public key which can be the same in all of these cases. And since the client owns the matching private key it can easily create a self-signed certificate with it which then matches the requirement of this specific public key.

Comment: Yeah, that's unfortunate. I briefly looked at ways to customise the client certificate validation with some Lua script in the NGINX config, but the `ngx_http_ssl_module` doesn't provide enough context in its exposed vars to drive such a script. Thanks for your suggestions.